# How to set dynamic entity to dbcontext Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I got a method that receives an entity like string to return a list of that entity.

What I want is set the entity dynamically and return the result.

What I need is something like this:

```
DbContext.Set <Type.GetType("Entity")>().Select(e => e);
```

This the error that I getting:

[image: Error]

Maybe this is not the correct to do so.

The `Set` method comes from Entity Framework Core.

[image: Set Method]

Comment: I believe `DbContext.Set(Type.GetType("Entity")...` should work

Comment: The problem is that I think in **EntityFrameworkCore** is not support.

Comment: Its a C# feature. It should work depending on the context. I did this long time ago.

Comment: Sorry! But the Set method come from **EntityFrameworkCore**.

Comment: The following says otherwise https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: I see the problem, sorry, the thing is that i am using **EntityFrameworkCore** not **EntityFramework 5 o 6**, this are others versions.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Try the Find function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.find?view=efcore-2.0

Comment: To my purpo I do not work because Find return a object and i need a **DbSet<TEntity>** or **IQueryable<TEntity>**.

Comment: I mentioned Find since I assumed you are searching for something using  Select. EFC simply has no non generic DbSet class.

Comment: You can't provide the type param via a method. It has to be a static type, i.e.: `context.Set<Entity>()`;

Comment: I just tried this works, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041821/dynamically-access-table-in-ef-core-2-0

Answer (score 1):

#### 1st - this is an example, not a solution for your specific problem.

**My entity class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyIdentityModel
{
    public class IdentityRole
    {
        public long Id { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset ActiveUntil { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**My Context**

```
using MyIdentityModel.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;

namespace MyIdentityModel
{

    public abstract class IdentityDbContextBase: DbContext
    {

        public IdentityDbContextBase(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        
        public DbSet<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; } = null!;
        

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityRoleConfiguration());
           
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Solution**
I have 3 approachs

```
public List<TResult> GetList<TResult>(DbContext context, string entityTypeName)
    where TResult : class
{
    Type entityType = Type.GetType(entityTypeName); // get type of entity / MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole
    var setMethod = context.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set), new Type[] { }).MakeGenericMethod(entityType); //Get Method Set<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>
    var dbSet = setMethod.Invoke(context, new object[] { }); // Calling context.Set<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>
    /* Call to another methods using reflection before calling "ToList" 
        Eg. example Where, Include, Select
        */
    var toListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList").MakeGenericMethod(entityType); //get Extension Method "ToList<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>"
    var list = (List<TResult>)toListMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { dbSet });//Calling "context.Set<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>.ToList<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>()" Method and convert to destination type if is possible.
    return list;
}

public List<TEntity> GetList2<TEntity>(DbContext context)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var setMethod = context.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set), new Type[] { }).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity)); //Get Method Set<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>
    var dbSet = setMethod.Invoke(context, new object[] { }); // Calling context.Set<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>
    /* Call to another methods using reflection before calling "ToList" 
        Eg. example Where, Include, Select
        */
    var toListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity)); //get Extension Method "ToList<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>"
    var list = (List<TEntity>)toListMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { dbSet });//Calling "context.Set<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>.ToList<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>()" Method and convert to destination type if is possible.
    return list;
}

public List<TEntity> GetList3<TEntity>(DbContext context)
    where TEntity : class
{
    return context.Set<TEntity>()/* Call to another methods before "ToList" */.ToList();
}
```

the main program calls.

1. Yo need the context, AssemblyQualifiedName = **parameters**. The type name of result = **type parameters**.

`public List<TResult> GetList<TResult>(DbContext context, string entityTypeName)`

2. Yo need the context = **parameters**. The type name of result = **type parameters**.

`public List<TEntity> GetList2<TEntity>(DbContext context)`

3. Yo need the context = **parameters**. The type name of result = **type parameters**.

`public List<TEntity> GetList3<TEntity>(DbContext context)`

```
Console.WriteLine("█ Result 1");
var result = GetList<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>(context, typeof(MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole).AssemblyQualifiedName);
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.Write("█ Result 2");
var result2 = GetList2<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>(context);
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result2));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.Write("█ Result 3");
var result3 = GetList3<MyIdentityModel.IdentityRole>(context);
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result3));
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: How would you call other methods like Where?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use **Generic type** Like Below:

```
DbContext.Set<T>().Select(e => e);
```

but For this Your Method Should **Works With Generics** Like Example at below (This Code **Not Tested**):

```
public Task<object> MyMethod<T>(T model)
{
   // some Code
}
```

You Can **Learn more** About it in This **[Link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics#:%7E:text=Generic%20means%20the%20general%20form,without%20the%20specific%20data%20type.)**

Sorry For Bad English.
I Wish its **Helps** ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy instance to spoof the binding of a generic method

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetEntity<T>() where T : class
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    Type spoofedType = typeof(InternalDbSet<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    //instance is only used to spoof the binding
    dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(spoofedType, context, spoofedType.Name);
    return SpoofedMethod(instance);
}

public IEnumerable<T> SpoofedMethod<T>(DbSet<T> _) where T : class
{
     return context.Set<T>().Select(e => e);
}
```

Activator.CreateInstance takes the type and passes the remaining parameters into the Type's constructor. InternalDbSet<> takes 2 parameters: DbContext and EntityTypeName. DbSet itself is an abstract, so you can't create an instance of it. If you check the type of a DbSet at runtime, then you'll see it is InternalDbSet.