# How to convert a string reference name to db-context model using c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core-2.2

Convert string reference name to a lambda expression query.

This is my tested code:

```
protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public AssetRequestController(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context; 
}

string tableName = "FlowStep";

var dbset = QueryExtensions.Query(_context, tableName);

public static partial class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable Query(this DbContext context, string entityName) =>
            context.Query(context.Model.FindEntityType(entityName).ClrType);

    static readonly MethodInfo SetMethod = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set));

    public static IQueryable Query(this DbContext context, Type entityType) =>
            (IQueryable)SetMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType).Invoke(context, null);
}
```

My DbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
   public DbSet<FlowStep> FlowStep { get; set; }
}
```

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core to dynamically add in lambda expressions to queries in EF.

I want to convert a string name (model name) to lambda expressions query. I found this answer.

[Dynamically access table in EF Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48042166/5268338)

But it gives an error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of >an object.'
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel.FindEntityType(...) returned >null.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use such code in the first place? If you want to base your query on SQL you can use `FromSQL` to pass the original query and [combine it with LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Comment: Apart from that, *entities* aren't tables. They are domain classes that are mapped to  database results that may come from one or more tables or queries. If you know the entity type, why not just use it? LINQ queries can be composed already, in fact every `from ... ` or `.Where()` adds yet another operator to an IQueryable query.

Comment: Finally, [the docs warn that Model isn't meant to be used by client code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.internal.model?view=efcore-2.1). There may not *be* a `Model` at the time you make that call. If you know you want the `FlowType` property why not request *that* with reflection?

Comment: _context."entityName", I'm parsing this **"entity name"** dynamically. but it will not be recognized as an entity

Comment: *Why*? You don't have to. In any case you are *not* parsing, you're trying to use an internal method that probably *doesn't* do what you expect. You can get the already configured `DbSet<FlowStep> FlowStep` property with reflection, eg `_context.GetType().GetProperty("FlowStep")` and read its value with `GetValue`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the reply, and it works fine, but I want a complete lambda expression with where clause. can you give an example?