# How to use the where clause with IQueryable<dynamic>

Tags: c#, sql, dynamic, reflection, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core with reflection to generate some forms dynamically.  Everything is working except the WHERE Clause.  I get the following error:

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

I am able to fix this by converting my IQueryable to a List, but that introduces different problems that i would like to avoid.

Here is my code:

```
public async void ViewCollection(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
    InversePropertyAttribute inversePropertyAttribute = (InversePropertyAttribute)ReflectionHelpers.GetAttribute(propertyInfo, typeof(InversePropertyAttribute));


    //GET THE TYPE OF THE COLLECTION
    Type collectionType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];

    //GET THE INVERSE PROPERTY INFO
    PropertyInfo inverseProperty = collectionType.GetProperty(inversePropertyAttribute.Property);

    //GET THE FOREIGN KEY ATTRIBUTE FROM THE INVERSE PROPERTY
    ForeignKeyAttribute foreignKeyAttribute = (ForeignKeyAttribute)ReflectionHelpers.GetAttribute(inverseProperty, typeof(ForeignKeyAttribute));

    //GET THE FOREIGN KEY PROPERTY FROM THE FOREIGN KEY ATTRIBUTE
    PropertyInfo foreignKeyProperty = collectionType.GetProperty(foreignKeyAttribute.Name);

    //GET INCLUDED TYPE NAMES BY FOREIGN KEY
    IEnumerable<string> includedTypes = collectionType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsClass).Where(p => ReflectionHelpers.HasAttribute(p, typeof(ForeignKeyAttribute))).Select(r => r.Name);

    //GET THE DATA SET
    IQueryable<dynamic> items = ReflectionHelpers.GetDbCollectionByType(Db, collectionType);

    //INCLUDE THE INCLUDED TYPES BY NAME
    foreach (string includedType in includedTypes) items = items.Include(includedType);

    //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
    items = items.Where(i => foreignKeyProperty.GetValue(i, null) == PrimaryKeyProperty.GetValue(Item, null));

    await ShowCollection(collectionType, items, propertyInfo.Name);
}
```

How can i solve this with out changing my type to a list?

Answer (score 2):

You can't build queries over `dynamic` because it's not supported natively in expression trees. Instead you should base your work on either non generic `IQueryable` or generic `IQueryable<object>`. e.g. if the `ReflectionHelpers.GetDbCollectionByType` is calling `DbContext.Set<T>` dynamically (similar to here [Dynamically access table in EF Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041821/dynamically-access-table-in-ef-core-2-0/48042166#48042166)), you should be able to cast it to `IQueryable<object>`:

```
var items = (IQueryable<object>)ReflectionHelpers.GetDbCollectionByType(Db, collectionType);
```

To add `Where` clause, you shouldn't use reflection calls inside the predicate expression, but build it dynamically using the `Expression` class methods (from `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace). Something like this:

```
// (object i) => (({collectionType})i).{ForeignKey} == Item.{PrimaryKey}
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "i");
var body = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(parameter, collectionType), foreignKeyProperty),
    Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(Item), PrimaryKeyProperty));
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(body, parameter);
```

and then

```
items = items.Where(predicate); // still IQueryable<object>
```

Comment: Ivan thank you for the effort.  When trying your suggestion i get this error:  Error CS1929 'IQueryable<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Where<TSource>(ParallelQuery<TSource>, Func<TSource, bool>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<TSource>'

Comment: Ivan, this is my code for GetDbCollectionByType:

(IQueryable<dynamic>)db.GetType().GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(propertyType).Invoke(db, null);

Comment: Change `IQueryable<dynamic>` to `IQueryable<object>`. This is what I used in my test `var items = (IQueryable<object>)typeof(DbContext).GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(collectionType).Invoke(db, null);` and it worked.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Wqk69c2 if you want to see an image

Comment: Hmm, interesting, you have `Include` but not `Where`. Very strange. When you type `items.Where`, what does Intellisense show? You are supposed to see 4 overloads - 2 for `IEnumerable<object>` and 2 for `IQueryable<object>`.

Comment: I get 5 overloads...hard to explain them

Comment: Only `items = ((IQueryable<object>)items).Where` should be needed. Add `using System.Linq;` or use `Queryable.Where` if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. IQueryable is part of language integrated query (LINQ) - it's statically typed, so you cannot use value types.

IQueryable behind the scenes is an expression tree that represents a query that has not yet been executed. The expression tree part represents the query. The static types represent the data that the query operates over.

Your best alternative is to build the expression tree by hand using the [expression tree API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/).